# Difference between _declspec and __declspec?

Tags: c++, c

I sometimes see keywords starting with two underscores and other times just one. Is there any difference?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe that `_declspec` is older name of the same Microsoft specific keyword `__declspec`. From a C++ Standard point of view, two underscores are more correct than a single underscore for an extension like this. That's according to 17.4.3.1.2/1:

> Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the implementation:
>
> - Each name that contains a double underscore (_  _) or begins with an underscore followed by an upper-
>     case letter (2.11) is reserved to the implementation for any use.
> - Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the
>     global namespace.

Comment: Correct. That means you cannot declare a `_declspec()` function in the global namespace called , but you are allowed to declare a `_declspec()` method. For that reason Microsoft can't use `_declspec` as a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword with two underscores `__declspec` should be used. While Microsoft compiler accepts the keyword with one underscore `_declspec`, it is only for compatibility reasons with the old compiler versions. It is not accepted by MSYS2 GCC. Therefore, using it would cause issues with GCC. [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/declspec?view=msvc-170) states the following:

> For compatibility with previous versions, _declspec is a synonym for __declspec unless compiler option /Za (Disable language extensions) is specified.