# How to use AMD power control function in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, amd-gpu

For a executable file or static lib, I know it can use

```
extern "C"
  {
    __declspec(dllexport) int AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance = 1;
  }
```

to select the high performance GPU, but how to use it in C# or dynamic link library?

Is there any other way to change the power saving mode setting?

Answer (score 0):

## **NvPatch & EditBinPE & EditPE & IL ASSEMBLY & C#**

To enable `AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance` you must use one of three applications, [nvpatch](https://www.toptensoftware.com/blog/nvpatch-how-it-works/), [EditBinPE](https://github.com/GabrielFrigo4/EditBinPE) or [EditPE](https://github.com/GabrielFrigo4/PyTools-and-PyUtils). Since so far it is not possible to export symbols in pure C# itself, it is only possible to do so directly in the IL assembly ...

### **EditBinPE**

[EditBinPE](https://github.com/GabrielFrigo4/EditBinPE) command: `editbinpe --enable-gpu filename.exe` or `editbinpe --enable filename.exe AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance`

### **EditPE/GPUPE**

[EditPE](https://github.com/GabrielFrigo4/PyTools-and-PyUtils) command: `editpe infile.exe outfile.exe "NvOptimusEnablement,1" "AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance,1"` or `gpupe infile.exe outfile.exe`

### **NvPatch**

[nvpatch](https://www.toptensoftware.com/blog/nvpatch-how-it-works/) command: `nvpatch --enable filename.exe`

### **IL Assembly**

```cs
.class public WindowsApplication1.ForceDedicatedGraphicCard
{
    .method public static uint32 AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance() cil managed
    {
        .export [2]
        ldc.i4.1
        ret
    }
}
```

### **END**

To check if it has been qualified use dumpbin:

`dumpbin.exe /exports your_project.exe`

Edit: this question looks like a duplicate of this one: [Forcing hardware accelerated rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270429/forcing-hardware-accelerated-rendering)