# Enable high-performance GPU for a .NET app

Tags: c#, c++, windows, nvidia

Users complained my app (uses Direct3D 11 to render some heavy 3D content for a CAD-like functionality) runs on Intel GPU on a dual-GPU systems.

Found that `NvOptimusEnablement` / `AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance` exported variables. However, the application has .NET frontend, can’t export things from there. While [there’s some workaround](http://lucasmagder.com/blog/2014/05/exporting-data-symbols-in-c-for-nvidia-optimus/), that recompilation step breaks debugger (can't set breakpoints anymore) and invalidates debug symbols, and I need them both to work reliably.

Any other ideas?

Is it possible to create nVidia application profile while installing?

Or, how do I use NVApi to select the high-performance GPU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ve made a C++ DLL with custom WIX action, that creates/updates the profile for the app when installing, and removes it when uninstalled.

While almost undocumented, the official nVidia API has the required NvAPI_DRS_* functions for that.

Here’s a workflow: `NvAPI_Initialize` (if failed it means the user doesn’t have nVidia GPU, that’s not an error), `NvAPI_DRS_CreateSession`, `NvAPI_DRS_LoadSettings`, `NvAPI_DRS_FindProfileByName`.

If was not found, `NvAPI_DRS_CreateProfile`, and three calls to `NvAPI_DRS_SetSetting`, setting three DWORD properties:

1. SHIM_MCCOMPAT_ID = SHIM_MCCOMPAT_ENABLE
2. SHIM_RENDERING_MODE_ID = SHIM_RENDERING_MODE_ENABLE
3. SHIM_RENDERING_OPTIONS_ID = SHIM_RENDERING_OPTIONS_DEFAULT_RENDERING_MODE

Then, call `NvAPI_DRS_GetProfileInfo` to get number of applications, followed by `NvAPI_DRS_EnumApplications`, and search for the EXE path.

When uninstalling, I delete the complete profile, by calling `NvAPI_DRS_FindProfileByName` and then `NvAPI_DRS_DeleteProfile`.

On reinstall and upgrade I do both, first remove then add.

Don't forget `NvAPI_DRS_SaveSettings` at the end.

P.S. Most unexpected thing is, nVidia “normalizes” paths stored in NVDRS_APPLICATION::appName field, they convert them to lowercase, and also replace `'\'` with `'/'`. Because of this “normalization”, no standard string comparison function will work for them.

Answer (score 0):

## **NvPatch & EditBinPE**

To enable `AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance` and `NvOptimusEnablement` you must use one of three applications, [nvpatch](https://www.toptensoftware.com/blog/nvpatch-how-it-works/), [EditBinPE](https://github.com/GabrielFrigo4/EditBinPE) or [EditPE](https://github.com/GabrielFrigo4/PyTools-and-PyUtils). These three applications serve to edit the header of the PE32+/PE64 file (only editbinpe and editpe does this type of file) and PE32

### **Using EditBinPE**

[EditBinPE](https://github.com/GabrielFrigo4/EditBinPE) command: `editbinpe --enable-gpu filename.exe`

### **Using EditPE/GPUPE**

[EditPE](https://github.com/GabrielFrigo4/PyTools-and-PyUtils) command: `gpupe infile.exe outfile.exe`

### **Using NvPatch**

[nvpatch](https://www.toptensoftware.com/blog/nvpatch-how-it-works/) command: `nvpatch --enable filename.exe`

Edit: this question looks like a duplicate of this one: [Forcing hardware accelerated rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270429/forcing-hardware-accelerated-rendering)