# Command to run an ".exe" file with NVIDIA Graphics card

Tags: windows, qt, graphics, windows-installer, nvidia

I have created an installer which contains an executable (".exe" file), which I want to run using the NVIDIA Graphics Processor ( Which is not the default option ). On my laptop I am able to achieve it by right clicking on the executable and selecting "Run with Graphics Processor" and then choose "High-Performance NVIDIA Processor". I am creating this installer using "Advanced Installer" and the executable is obtained from a "Qt Creator" C++ Application. Goal is to create an installer which will run the executable by default with "High-Performance NVIDIA Processor" always.

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823372/forcing-machine-to-use-dedicated-graphics-card

Comment: Is it possible to do so from the command prompt?

Comment: Thanks Tushar your suggestion worked.

Answer (score -2):

You can go to Nvidia control panel and look for manage 3D settings in 3D settings then program settings then select add then look up to your *.exe* file then choose to run it with high performance Nvidia processor then click apply and by that each time you are going to run your *.exe* file the file will run automatically using Nvidia GPU.

---

### Steps

1. Navigate to: Nvidia Control Panel > 3D Settings > Manage 3D Settings > Program Settings > Add
2. Look up your *.exe* file and choose to run it with *high performance Nvidia processor*
3. Click Apply

Comment: Can this be done using PowerShell?

Answer (score -2):

If you run `cmd.exe` with the graphics card anything from there will use that graphics card.

Comment: What does this mean? How does one do this?