# Intel Arc Force Dedicated Graphic

Tags: c++, graphics

I am trying to make a wrapper for C++ to always enforce x app is using dedicated graphics. The issue is I can't figure out how to force Dedicated graphics (Discrete) GPU on Intel Arc. Here is the code for AMD / NVIDIA pulled from a previous similar question found here. [Forcing Machine to Use Dedicated Graphics Card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823372/forcing-machine-to-use-dedicated-graphics-card)

```
extern "C"
{
  __declspec(dllexport) unsigned long NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;
  __declspec(dllexport) int AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance = 1;
}
```